# Convert sql table to json

Tags: python, sql, json, pandas

I am trying to fetch data from mysql server, and to save it as json.

BUT somehow when transforming to json, date format gets lost. Look at *start* & *end* in data and output.

Making connection:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
from pandas import *


con='mysql+pymysql://username:password@host/table'

data=pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM calendar_table',con)
```

data i get looks like:

```
   id                title               start                 end  client
0   1  somethinginterestin 2018-06-21 12:00:00 2018-06-21 16:20:00    suja
1   2                vusce 2018-06-21 15:00:00 2018-06-22 08:00:00  vuscec
```

then i used *pandas* to create json file

```
x = data.to_json(orient='records')

f = open("sqltable.json","w+")
f.write(x)
f.close()
```

the file output

```
[{"id":1,"title":"somethinginterestin","start":1529582400000,"end":1529598000000,"client":"suja"},
{"id":2,"title":"vusce","start":1529593200000,"end":1529654400000,"client":"vuscec"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use parameter `date_format='iso'`:

```
In [260]: df.to_json(orient='records', date_format='iso')
Out[260]: '[{"id":1,"title":"somethinginterestin","start":"2018-06-21T12:00:00.000Z","end":"2018-06-21T16:20:00.000Z","client":"suja"},{"id":2,"title":"vusce","
start":"2018-06-21T15:00:00.000Z","end":"2018-06-22T08:00:00.000Z","client":"vuscec"}]'
```

from [Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_json.html):

> **date_format** : {None, 'epoch', 'iso'}
>
> Type of date conversion. `epoch` = epoch milliseconds, `'iso'` = ISO8601.
>
> **The default depends on the `orient`.**
>
> **For `orient='table'`, the default is `'iso'`.**
>
> **For all other orients,
>      the default is `'epoch'`**.